# Cypher: Extract node and relationship properties from path

Tags: neo4j, cypher, extract

I would like to extract from a path properties from nodes and relationships.
I can do it separately for nodes and relationships using the following queries.

`extract(n IN nodes(path)| n.name)`

`extract(r IN relationships(path)| r.metric)`

Is there a way to extract names and metrics from path elements in a list that looks as following
`[name1, metric1, name2, metric2, name3]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` for combining arrays:

```
WITH path,
     extract(n IN nodes(path)| n.name) as names,
     extract(r IN relationships(path)| r.metric) as metrics
RETURN HEAD(names) + 
       REDUCE(acc = [], i in RANGE(1,size(metrics)) | 
              acc  + metrics[i-1] + names[i])
```